# dimension set of all fourier series functions and basis

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $F$ be the set of all functions on $D = [0,2 \pi] \times [0,2 \pi]$ that have a convergent Fourier series.

- Is the dimension of $F$ equal to $\aleph_{0}$?
- Given a countable infinity of linearly independent functions $B$ that also have a convergent Fourier series, is it possible to use it as a basis for $F$?

Thanks

Comment: By the usual notion of dimension (via Hamel Bases), your space has dimension strictly greater than $\aleph_0$. It would help if you told us what exactly the "dimension" of an infinite space means in this context (i.e. do we "allow infinite sums").

Comment: Please excuse my unclear question, I'm lacking knowledge about functional analysis.  I meant dimension as in the linear algebra context, and infinite sums are allowed. Thanks

Comment: Ok, now I see what you mean. Would it help if I modify the definition of $F$ as the set of all functions $D=[0,2\pi] \times [0,2\pi]$ that have a convergent Fourier series and are also continuous and integrable?

Comment: You should note in particular that the *usual* linear algebra definition doesn't allow infinite sums of basis elements, hence the need for Hamel bases (as opposed to Schauder bases).  Also, what do you mean when you say that a function "has a convergent Fourier series"?  Can we suppose you mean convergence with respect to the $L^2$ norm?

Comment: Ok. In my specific problem $F$ is a set of functions that satisfy the Dirichlet conditions for the existence of a Fourier Series and they all have finite $L^2$ norm. $B$ is a set of countably infinite, linearly independent functions that satisfy the Dirichlet conditions and all have finite $L^2$ norm. But since I need infinite sums to express $F$ in terms of $B$, do I need further conditions for convergence of these sums?

Comment: What does it mean for a sum of functions to converge?

Comment: Ok, I reviewed the theorems for the conditions for convergence of a Fourier series for different types. I see now that in my specific problem, since $F$ and $B$ are actually sets of probability distributions that have a continuous derivative and are square integrable I can achieve pointwise and $L^2$ convergence.  However I can't achieve uniform convergence unless I add $1$ to the basis and have a zero normal gradient .

Comment: Thank you for your patience and your corrections. I think pointwise convergence will do fine for my specific problem.